# Non-tenured to tenured track?

Tags: career-path, tenure-track, non-tenure

Our faculty voted last year to allow any teaching faculty member to request going from being non-tenured to tenured.  Our dean has now denied this request.  Are there other universities offering this option? what are the pros and cons? and should we attempt to fight this?

Comment: To get proper answers, it would help if you could give a bit more context. Where in the world are you? "Our faculty voted last year" <- what was the status of that vote; is that from some official council meeting, or an informal vote in a bar? "Our dean has now denied this request" <- does that mean that the dean denied the request process wholesale, or that they denied your individual request? "Should we attempt to fight this" <- what exactly is it, that is to be fought?

Comment: To clarify, the vote was to allow non-tenure track teaching faculty to request/apply to be considered for being on a tenure track, perhaps with different criteria than those hired on to the classic tenure track? Perhaps after $n$ years of teaching, or some other bar?

Comment: Related: [How common is it to switch to a tenure-track position from a non-tenure-track position in the same institution?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/71488/68109)

Answer (score 0):

Why were faculty allowed to vote on deciding their own tenure? Presumably the dean didn't sanction the vote, which is why they are denying requests. I don't understand why any university would invite faculty to award themselves tenure. Tenure is a form of promotion, granted by universities, not by faculty.

Comment: This reads more as a comment than as an answer.

Comment: @user111388 _Are there other universities offering this option?_ No, _I don't understand why..._ _what are the pros and cons?_ All cons for the university: _Tenure is a form of promotion..._ _and should we attempt to fight this?_ No, based upon my points, the OP can't win, the university will never agree.

Comment: "Why were faculty allowed to vote on deciding their own tenure?" There are quite a few universities which have some sort of self-government and where the faculty or some of their elected representatives have a binding vote in such decisions. Right now the question lacks too much context to give an answer and this is definitely not one.

Comment: @mlk I answer based upon by best understanding. I agree the question lacks context, that limited my ability to answer.